# Typescript: get duplicate object only if certain fields are equal

Tags: javascript, typescript

So there's lots answers to this if the objects are equal. But in my case I want return only if certain fields are equal and i haven't been able to find any answers to this.

Let's say i have this array of objects:

```
let obj = [
  { name: 'bob', adress: 'somewhere1', country: 'sweden', nr: '1235'},
  { name: 'bob', adress: 'somewhere1', country: 'norway', nr: '7656'},
  { name: 'john', adress: 'somewhere2', country: 'denmark', nr: '54534'},
  { name: 'john', adress: 'somewhere2', country: 'US', nr: '3333'},
  { name: 'steven', adress: 'somewhere3', country: 'UK', nr: '5467'}
]
```

I want to filter this by name and address if they are equal, add them to a new array:

```js
let newObj = [
  [{
      name: 'bob',
      adress: 'somewhere1',
      country: 'sweden',
      nr: '1235'
    },
    {
      name: 'bob',
      adress: 'somewhere1',
      country: 'norway',
      nr: '7656'
    }
  ],
  [{
      name: 'john',
      adress: 'somewhere2',
      country: 'denmark',
      nr: '54534'
    },
    {
      name: 'john',
      adress: 'somewhere2',
      country: 'US',
      nr: '3333'
    }
  ],
  [{
    name: 'steven',
    adress: 'somewhere3',
    country: 'UK',
    nr: '5467'
  }]
]
```

Comment: What have you tried? I suggest you take some time to think about the steps needed to solve this problem. Describe those steps in words. The more clearly you can think about the solution in a human language, the more easily it will be to implement it in a computer language.

Comment: OP, it looks like you arent trying to filter, but instead group on a particular parameter.  For example, you may be grouping on name and adress.  Also, i must say that your Code is invalid JSON.

Comment: http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/object-equality-in-javascript.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const arr = [
  { name: 'bob', address: 'somewhere1', country: 'sweden', nr: '1235'},
  { name: 'bob', address: 'somewhere1', country: 'norway', nr: '7656'},
  { name: 'john', address: 'somewhere2', country: 'denmark', nr: '54534'},
  { name: 'john', address: 'somewhere2', country: 'US', nr: '3333'},
  { name: 'steven', address: 'somewhere3', country: 'UK', nr: '5467'}
];

const grouped = Object.values(arr.reduce((accum, item) => {
  const nameAndAddress = `${item.name}${item.address}`;
  if (!accum[nameAndAddress]) accum[nameAndAddress] = [];
  accum[nameAndAddress].push(item);
  return accum;
}, {}));
```

This will use the name and address combined as a unique identifier and separate the records out into arrays on that identifier, then pull those arrays out of the resulting object into an array as in your desired output.